# Send data to client page from mysql database without refreshing page (timeout)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I created a tabulation system for beauty pageants that show judges score on a projector. I created a presentation page for that using Codeigniter.

The HTML from that presentation page is purely written in Javascript. The page refreshes each second to get real-time data sent by the judges.

The not-so-cool thing about this logic is that when the page writes a lot of data, the page blinks every second. So the refreshing of the page is noticeable and somewhat disturbing.

This is a snippet of the code I'm working on.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                getJudgesScore();

                setInterval(function(){
                    if (getNumFinalists() == 0)
                        getJudgesScore();
                    else {
                        window.open ('presentationFinalists','_self',false)
                    }

                    },1000);
            });
```

You can imagine how much data is being sent and received every time this code is executed.

To sum this up, what I want to accomplish is instead of the client asking for data every second, the server initiates the connection every time a new data is saved to the database. Thank you for taking your time reading my concern.

[image: Presentation page]

Comment: It is impossible for the server to initiate a connection to the client. You should look into implementing it via AJAX so that you can just request the necessary data and manipulate the page via JavaScript instead of requesting the whole page. Additionally, you could use timestamps so that if no data has changed since the last update (timestamp passed in the ajax request), the server simply reports that nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you to take necessary data from mysql server and send to client page.
Timer jquery run for after perticular time of interval.

```
        <script src="../JS/Timer/jquery.timer.js"></script>
        var timer = $u.timer(function() {
          getJudgesScore();
        });
        timer.set({time: 1000, autostart: true});
```

refer this link also
      https://code.google.com/p/jquery-timer/source/browse/trunk/jquery.timer.js?r=12

Answer (score 0):

What you are attempting is a tricky -- but not impossible -- proposition.

@Chelsea is right -- the server can't genuinely initiate a connection to the client -- but there are several technologies that can emulate that functionality, using client connections that are held open for future events.

Those that come to mind are EventSource, Web Sockets, and long polling... all of which have various advantages and disadvantages. There's not one "correct" answer, but Google (and Stack Overflow) are your friends.

Of course, by "server," above, I'm referring to the web server, not the database. The web server would need to notify the appropriate clients of data changes as it posts them to the database.

To get real-time notification of events from the MySQL server itself (delivered to the web server) is also possible, but requires access to and decoding of the replication event stream, which is a complicated proposition.  The discovered events would then need to result in an action by the web server to notify the listening clients over the already-established connections using one of the mechanisms above.

You could also continue to poll the server from the browser, but use only exchange enough data via ajax to update what you need.  If you included some kind of indicator in your refresh requests, such as a timestamp you received in the prior update, or some kind of monotonic global version ID such as the MySQL `UUID_SHORT()` function generates, you could send a very lightweight `204 No Content` response to the client, indicating that the browser did not need to update anything.